# sms through GSM mobile

Tags: vb.net

Could any body give me code how to send sms through GSM mobiles, connected with computer?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: Are you talking about a GSM modem or a GSM phone? If it's a phone, which model / OS?

Answer (score 1):

About one year ago I have used [mCore](http://www.logixmobile.com/products/mcorelib/index.asp) library for this purpose.
It is very simple to use (if my VB.NET is correct):

```
Private objSMS As New mCore.SMS()

' Set up connection and check '
' if connection is open '
Private Sub SendSms()
    If Not objSMS.IsConnected Then
        objSMS.Port = "COM4"
        objSMS.BaudRate = mCore.BaudRate.BaudRate_19200
        objSMS.DataBits = mCore.DataBits.Eight
        objSMS.Parity = mCore.Parity.None
        objSMS.StopBits = mCore.StopBits.One
        objSMS.FlowControl = mCore.FlowControl.None
        objSMS.DisableCheckPIN = False
        objSMS.Encoding = mCore.Encoding.Unicode_16Bit
    End If
    Dim strSendResult As String = objSMS.SendSMS("+7921XXXXXXX", "Server CORP_DB2 is down!", False)
End Sub
```

This library supports a lot of mobile phones and has a lot of useful functions: sending USSD requests, receiving incoming SMS and so on.

mCore is shareware but it has trial version. Trial version will add text to all SMSs that SMS sent by mCore.